# Bottom white line on inside

Tags: html, css

I am cloning Quizlet.com. Stuck on the home screen style.
Hovering over a card adds an underline to indicate that the card is selected.

When not hovering: quizlet:

[image]
my site:
[image]

When hovering over a quizlet:
[image]

When hovering over my site:
[image]

I added border-bottom to the css and it was added outside the area, not inside the area of the div tag.

edit:
The phenomenon of cards being pushed out has been resolved. But I don't like the shadows going under the cards. I'll attach a photo.

[image]

Comment: Look at using `outline` instead of `border`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try two options:

- `box-shadow`
- `::after` pseudo element

#### [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow):

Probably the shortest solution - creating a `box-shadow` that is only visible on the bottom, achieved by specifying the same `blur` and `spread` (3rd and 4th parameters respectively).

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #1E2230;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

div:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 2px 2px white;
}

body {
  background-color: #ededed;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

<sup>Notice: Non-compliant with the OP's requirements - the outline is on the outside, not inside</sup>

#### [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo element

Absolutely position an element with a height of `0px` and a width of `100%` with a border of `10px` on the bottom of the `div` whose `position` must be `relative`.

I would recommend this solution seeing how it's easily customizable and understandable.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #1E2230;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  position: relative;
}

div:hover:after {
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 10px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #ededed;
}
```

```html
<div></div>d
```

Comment: OK. But I want the shadow to be within the div tag area. I'll add a description. @Spectirc

Answer (score 0):

I think you will know what's done in that div in Quizlet if you use devtool and target that specific div.